# How to enable options using checkboxes and saving them through local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I started learning jQuery and Javascript not so long ago, and I have encountered some issues with the local storage. I am trying to control select - options using checkboxes, however my code does not work with jQuery 1.11.0, as I used 1.4.4 for this before.

Result expected: When I click on any box, the option linked with it will be enabled and saved in local storage. Also, when I select manually all checkboxes, the select all checkbox will be checked (this works now, but only on first attempt), and when one checkbox is not selected, the select all element will be unchecked automatically. Also, the select/unselect all checkbox does not work as it should.

This is what I had previously http://jsfiddle.net/tfgqhxdw/, code which worked with 1.4.4 jQuery library, however I would need it to work with 1.11.0 as I have other functions that are in conflict with this old library.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$(function enableall_push() {
    $(".checkbox2").click(function(){
        var b = $(".checkbox2");
        if(b.length == b.filter(":checked").length){
            $("#enableall_push").attr("checked","checked");
        } else {
            $("#enableall_push").removeAttr("checked","checked");
        }
    });

    $('#enableall_push').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.checkbox2').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
                localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
            });
            //FUNCTION
        } else {
            $('.checkbox2').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;

            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');               
                localStorage.setItem(this.value,'');
            });
            //FUNCTION
        }
    });
}); 

$(function push101 () {
    $("#push1").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push1").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});

$(function push103 () {
    $("#push2").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push2").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});

$(function push105 () {
    $("#push3").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push3").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all your:

```
 $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]')
```

to

```
$("#reasonDrop option[value='103^1']")
```

You're missing the correct quotation marks.

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krfud885/)

Comment: Thank you! It seems that now it's working, however, I see that the enable all does not change to checked when having all other boxes checked, just on first attempt. Any idea what this might cause?

Comment: I've modified the jquery a bit (new function and changed attr to prop) - hope it resolves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/krfud885/1/ - can you mark as accepted answer if so please :) thanks

Comment: It does work perfectly online, however, I would need it to work offline too. Offline, the enable all is not checked on refresh (in case all boxes are checked). Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: I included the onload="checkChecked()" to body, however it looks ineffective in my project. However, it does work if I have only have the codes from jsfiddle. Any idea how could I recall the function effectively, so that it can work within my project on refresh?

Comment: You could try calling it with $(document).ready(function(){checkChecked();}); I'm not sure why it wouldn't work offline.

Comment: I just fixed this, and it works perfectly! I just recalled the function you provided me with at the end of the .js file:    window.onload = function() {
 checkChecked();
} . Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your select option syntax is wrong; 101^1 instead of 101_1.

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5gaovwxe/3/).

// ENABLE ALL PUSH OPTIONS

```
$(function enableall_push() {
    $(".checkbox2").click(function(){
        var b = $(".checkbox2");
        if(b.length == b.filter(":checked").length){
            $("#enableall_push").attr("checked","checked");
        } else {
            $("#enableall_push").removeAttr("checked","checked");
        }
    });

    $('#enableall_push').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.checkbox2').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
                localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
            });
            //FUNCTION
        } else {
            $('.checkbox2').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;

            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');               
                localStorage.setItem(this.value,'');
            });
            //FUNCTION
        }
    });
});
```

// 101 ------------------

```
$(function push101 () {
    $("#push1").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push1").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=101_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

// 103 ------------------

```
$(function push103 () {
    $("#push2").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push2").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=103^1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

// 105 ------------------

```
$(function push105 () {
    $("#push3").each(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

    $("#push3").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').removeAttr('disabled');
            localStorage.setItem(this.value,'checked');
        } else {
            $('#reasonDrop option[value=105_1]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            localStorage.removeItem(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the value, as I need them unchanged. It is part of the tool I am building, these are the default values I need to go on with "101^1, ...". Is there another way to make this work? However, I see that even the values changed, the enable all checkboxes does not change to checked when having all other boxes checked, just on first attempt.